# Computing probabilities in a non-Markovian chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

If I wanted to create a chain that is not Markov. Lets say the states are **R : Rainy day** and **S : Sunny day**. Now say the probability of tomorray is  a rainy day depends on if today is rainy or not and if yesterday was rainy or not. Now assume we know the probabilities :

$P(X_i=S\vert X_{i-1}=S,X_{i-2}=S)$

$P(X_i=S\vert X_{i-1}=S,X_{i-2}=R)$

$P(X_i=S\vert X_{i-1}=R,X_{i-2}=S)$

$P(X_i=S\vert X_{i-1}=R,X_{i-2}=R)$

$P(X_i=R\vert X_{i-1}=S,X_{i-2}=S)$

$P(X_i=R\vert X_{i-1}=S,X_{i-2}=R)$

$P(X_i=R\vert X_{i-1}=R,X_{i-2}=S)$

$P(X_i=R\vert X_{i-1}=R,X_{i-2}=R)$

How do I compute for example $P(X_i=S \vert X_{i-1}=S)$?

Comment: Can't you just recast this as a Markov chain with $4$ states: RR, RS, SR, SS?

Comment: I don't understand. I am looking for simple example of something that is not a Markov chain to study why some properties don't hold anymore. Why would I transform it into a Markov chain?

Comment: If you know the steady-state probabilities of the $4$ states, then you can compute the desired probabilities, right?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're looking for, but often you can deal with a process that is not a Markov chain by converting it to a Markov chain.